# Adding conditional where clause in codeiginter activerecord

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I am trying to build a query to search available hotels in a website developed in Codeigniter.
I have two separate tables , "Hotels" to store hotel details, and "Calendar" to store dates and availability. 
"Hotels" table has id , hotel_title ,details 
"Calendar" table has id (hotel id) , date , status (booked / available)

Here is my code to get available hotels on a particular date

```
if($this->input->get('date')){
    $this->db->where('calendar.date' , $this->input->get('date'));
    $this->db->where('calender.status !=' , 'booked');
}
$this->db->select('hotels.id , hotels.title, hotels.details');
$this->db->from('hotels');
$this->db->join('calender' , 'hotels.id = calendar.id' , 'left outer');
$this->db->get()->results();
```

Lets say there is a hotel that is booked on 2014-07-25, and available on 2014-07-26.
when we search for 2014-07-25, it doesn't appear in the results , when we search for 2014-07-26 It appears. The problem is, I want the hotel to be available (appear in the results) by default if it has no status saved in calendar table for some date, for example, now if I search for that hotel on 2014-07-27 (There is no row saved it "calendar" having this date and id of this particular hotel), It does not appear in the results. 
I will appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your where condition in join on clause condition.

```
if($this->input->get('date')){
   $this->db->join('calender' , 'hotels.id = calendar.id AND calendar.date={$this->input->get('date')} AND calender.status != "booked"' , 'left outer');
}else{
  $this->db->join('calender' , 'hotels.id = calendar.id' , 'left outer');
}
```

This is sample code. Change according to your needs

Comment: Unfortunately it shows results even if they are booked